# List directories which contain an edited file

Tags: linux, directory, find

I have a complex directory structure with many directories, each directory has many subdirectories and each subdirectory has many more subdirectories and files.

I want a list of the top level directories which contain files which have been edited in the last 24 hours.

I've used `find . -mtime -1 -ls` to list all the edited files but I'm only interested in the top directory they are in not the files themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -mtime -1 | awk -F/ '!a[$2]++ { print $2 }'
```

To be specific with checking of files (not directories):

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -mtime -1 | awk -F/ '!a[$2]++ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: Good one! Also was about to post an additional `awk` solution since it saves from two additional processes compared to my solution. You were faster! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following pipe will do:

```
find -mindepth 2 -mtime -1 | sed 's#\./\([^/]*\).*#\1#' | sort | uniq
```

Note that I'm using `-mindepth 2` to prevent find from returning files which had been changed but are located in the current folder and not in a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec dirname {} \;
```